# Flask: peewee.OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: python, flask, peewee

[image]

I'm trying to run https://github.com/swifthorseman/flask-peewee-heroku-setup locally on win 10, using python 3.6. I'm not sure if this project is designed to be run locally, maybe its only designed for heroku.

I have run the file teletubbies.py locally which created the db and table as you can see in the screenshot. To run it locally  (or try to) I added the lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

and I'm running it using

```
python server.py
```

The entire server.py file as I have it:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, g
from tellytubbies import retrieve_all, db_proxy

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = db_proxy
    g.db.connect()

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    g.db.close()
    return response

@app.route('/')
def index():
    tellytubbies = retrieve_all()
    return render_template("index.html", tellytubbies=tellytubbies)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

By stepping through the code I don't see an error until the line:

```
tellytubbies = retrieve_all()
```

Which then crashes giving the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "...\server.py", line 18, in index
    tellytubbies = retrieve_all()
  File "...\tellytubbies.py", line 32, in retrieve_all
    for tellytubby in TellyTubby.select().order_by(TellyTubby.name):
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3281, in __iter__
    return iter(self.execute())
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3274, in execute
    self._qr = ResultWrapper(model_class, self._execute(), query_meta)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2939, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3837, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3656, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 135, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "....myfile\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3830, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: no such table: tellytubby
```

The retrieve_all() function comes from the teletubbies.py file:

```
def retrieve_all():
    results = []
    for tellytubby in TellyTubby.select().order_by(TellyTubby.name):
        results.append(tellytubby)
    return results
```

the teletubbies.py does work when I run it as

```
python teletubbies.py
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: When you run `python teletubbies.py` what is the output? The `teletubbies.py` script is responsible for creating the table.

Comment: The output is :Dipsy Laa-Laa Po Tinky Winky -  as expected.

Comment: Can you verify that table 'tellytubby' get created successfully? You could use psql CLI to check that 'psql -U username -d mydatabase -c 'SELECT * FROM tellytubby''

Comment: I'm using sqlite locally. I'm using pycharm with the datagrip plugin. When I run 'SELECT * FROM tellytubby' I get the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flask server works fine for me, *after* I run `python teletubbies.py` to initialize the sqlite database. However, if I remove the `tellytubbies.db` file that was created by running the script directly, the flask server fails with the same exception you quote.

Something to consider here is that when you run `tellytubbies.py`, the database file `tellytubbies.db` will be created in *whatever directory you run it from*. If you then run `server.py` from a different directory - for instance, if your IDE is running it - it won't find the other `tellytubbies.db`, so a new one will be created; but becase the tables were only created in your `__main__` section in `tellytubbies.py`, the tables won't be created.

So your flask server needs to do some of the initialization that `teletubbies.py` is doing. I replaced the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section of your `server.py` with the following and it it works. It will work whether you keep the same database file or remove it between runs to start from scratch. I've added a check to make sure the same rows don't get inserted repeatedly.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from teletubbies import add_tellytubbies, TellyTubby
    db_proxy.connect()
    db_proxy.create_tables([TellyTubby], safe=True)
    if TellyTubby.select().count() == 0:
        add_tellytubbies()
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work, but I'm still not sure why you have to create tables that already exist in the sqlite db.

Comment: You don't! The error you were getting means that the database itself - `tellytubbies.db` - didn't exist. sqlite will automatically create a new database if you point it at a nonexistent file. The most likely reason for the database not existing, I think, is that you were running `flask.py` and `tellytubbies.py` from different directories. I'll update my answer to add some more detail.

Comment: @user61629 - see the second paragraph of my edited answer for more details about what's going on. Hope that helps!

Comment: 'the database file tellytubbies.db will be created in whatever directory you run it from.' - Wow , that may be my problem. Is there a way to control where the sqlite file is created and looked for?

Comment: You can use an absolute path (like "c:\path\to\file"), or if you just want the database file to be in a consistent place, you could use `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), 'tellytubbies.py')`

Comment: Thank you but how do you set that with peewee?

Comment: The line that determines the database path is in `tellytubbies.py` - `db = SqliteDatabase('tellytubbies.db')`. The single-quoted string there is the file name for the database. If you replace it with the `os.path.join...` that I put above (except for replacing `tellytubbies.py` with `tellytubbies.db`, that was a typo!) that will put your database in the same directory every time.